# My wifi isn't working like it used to work before

Tags: wireless

I am using a Lenovo laptop which was bought recently. My wifi used to work perfectly fine until few days back. And now it is connecting to the wifi, but it is not connecting to the internet.
P.S. I am a beginner.
I also saw many people asking the same question on ubuntu forum. But none of their problems have got solved.

Comment: Someone posted something almost identical to this just a few days ago, except in their case they attributed the failure to having upgraded from 12.04LTS to 14.04LTS.

Answer (score 0):

It might be due to the issue with network manager. Try the below command

```
 sudo service dbus restart

 sudo service network-manager restart
```